# Error in converting Range to arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Anybody please help me figure my problem out?

```
Dim attPresent as Variant ' attpresent()
Set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws.cells(Rows.count, 8).end(xlup).row

attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value 'errors if I use Dim attPresent() As Variant

For k = LBound(attPresent, 1) To UBound(attPresent, 1) ' Dim attPresent As Variant'errors if I use         
    msgbox attpresent(k,1)
Next
```

This line `attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value` returns an error if I declare the variable as `Dim attPresent() As Variant`. Whereas, if declare the variable as `Dim attPresent As Variant`, this line `For k = LBound(attPresent, 1) To UBound(attPresent, 1)` errors.

Can anyone please help me clear this out?Thanks

Comment: what line are you getting your error ? using `Dim attPresent() As Variant` at the first line runs fine on my sheet

Comment: did u assign lastrow's value, and set ws ?

Comment: @ramj see my answer below, let me know if it solved your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to separate the stuff that you had already defined but for clarity I thought I'd provide my full code:

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow, i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim attPresent() As Variant

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim attPresent(lastrow - 4)

For i = 4 To lastrow
    attPresent(i - 4) = ws.Range("H" & i).Value
Next

msg = Join(attPresent, " ")
MsgBox "The array holds: " & vbNewLine & msg

End Sub
```

I defined the array without a size to begin with then redefined it to the size it needs to be at a later stage once you know the lastrow (as you started on 4 i deducted 4 from `lastrow`).

I guessed the msgBox was to test what you had gathered so I created a dump that prints them all into one box but obviously change that if you have a lot of data. xD

To work with arrays I always loop through each individual entry, storing them one at a time. I'm not even sure whether you can dump an entire range into one in one step as I've never even looked into it. Anyway, I hope this solves your problem kupo.

Answer (score 3):

As a good practice, try to remember to use `Option Explicit`, and also declare all your variables.

When you use `Dim attPresent() As Variant` to declare you array , and later on you insert values from a Range to your Array with `attPresent = .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value`, it will automatically `Redim` your array to 2-dimensinal array (1 to Row number, 1 to Column Number).

```
Option Explicit

Sub RngtoArray()

Dim attPresent() As Variant  
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim k As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    attPresent = .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value
End With

For k = 1 To UBound(attPresent, 1)
    MsgBox attPresent(k, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: A slightly different approach, in case there is only 1 cell in the Range:

```
With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    ' for single column only - create a 1-Dimension array
    ReDim attPresent(1 To lastrow - 4 + 1) ' when the Range starts from "H4"

    For k = 1 To UBound(attPresent)
        attPresent(k) = .Cells(4 + k - 1, "H")
    Next k

End With


For k = 1 To UBound(attPresent)
    MsgBox attPresent(k)
Next
```

Comment: I've already figured the problem out. My code will error if my `lastrow` is also `4`, while if it's not, it doesn't throw an error. Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: You could do: `If lastrow = 4 then attpresent = array(.Range("H4").Value) else attPresent = .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value`. Note your loop should go from `LBound` to `Ubound` rather than `1 to Ubound`

Comment: @ramj try the edited code in the section below (under `Edit 1`)

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for the updates. But the code now returns `Type Mismatch error again` on this line `attPresent = .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value`. Thanks

Comment: @ramj but this is not the code in my latest update, copy the relevant code from **Edit1** section

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, it does the same as Glitch_Doctor answer :) Thanks for this :)

Comment: @ramj then please mark his answer with a **V** (or mine), whichever suits your need better

Answer (score 1):

```
Function RangeToArray(rng As Range)
Dim myArray() As Variant, ws As Worksheet
fr = rng.Row
fc = rng.Column
r = rng.Rows.Count
c = rng.Columns.Count
Set ws = rng.Worksheet
ReDim myArray(r - 1, c - 1)
For i = 0 To r - 1
    For j = 0 To c - 1
        myArray(i, j) = ws.Cells(fr + i, fc + j).Value2
    Next j
Next i
RangeToArray = myArray
End Function

Sub f()
Dim rng As Range, attPresent() As Variant ' attpresent()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow)
attPresent = RangeToArray(rng)

For k = LBound(attPresent, 1) To UBound(attPresent, 1) ' Dim attPresent As Variant'errors if I use
    MsgBox attPresent(k, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

I created a more generic function that you can call in this specific case as well.